# Erro de iniciante linguagem C Code blocks

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main();
{int dinheiro = 200};
int r$100, r$50, r$20, r$10, r$5, r$2, r$1;
int inter;

while(dinheiro > 0) {

        if (dinheiro >= 100) {
        r$100 = dinheiro/100;
            dinheiro = dinheiro - r$100*100;
        }
        else{r$100 = 0;}
        if((dinheiro >= 50) && (dinheiro < 100)) {
        r$50 = dinheiro/50;
            dinheiro = dinheiro - r$50*50;
        }
        else{r$50 = 0;}
        if ((dinheiro >= 20) && (dinheiro < 50)) {
        r$20 = dinheiro/20;
            dinheiro = dinheiro - r$20*20 ;
        }
        else{r$20 = 0;}
        if ((dinheiro >= 10) && (dinheiro < 20)) {
        r$10 = dinheiro/10;
            dinheiro = dinheiro - r$10*10;
        }
        else{r$10 = 0;}
        if ((dinheiro >= 5) && (dinheiro < 10)) {
        r$5 = dinheiro/5;
            dinheiro = dinheiro - r$5*5;
        }
        else{r$5 = 0;}
        if ((dinheiro >= 2) && (dinheiro < 10)) {
        r$2 = dinheiro/2;
            dinheiro = dinheiro - r$2*2;
        }
        else{r$2 = 0;}
        if ((dinheiro >= 1) && (dinheiro < 1)) {
        r$1 = dinheiro/1;
            dinheiro = dinheiro - r$1*1;
        }
        else{r$1 = 0;}

        printf("notas de r$100 = %d\n", r$100);
        printf("notas de r$50 = %d\n", r$50);
        printf("notas de r$20 = %d\n", r$20);
        printf("notas de r$10 = %d\n", r$10);
        printf("notas de r$5 = %d\n", r$5);
        printf("notas de r$2 = %d\n", r$2);
        printf("notas de r$1 = %d\n", r$1);
        return 0;




}
```

Comment: Não tem sentido este {} na declaração de dinheiro. O caractere $ não é um caractere válido para se utilizar em um identificador. Da próxima vez informe qual erro está ocorrendo. O operador = é o operador de atribuição, me parece que você quer verificar uma igualdade e, neste caso, deve utilizar o operador ==.

Comment: Caro @anonimo o $ ali é parte dos nomes das variáveis, no gcc 6.3 funcionou normalmente https://ideone.com/Vck8bN.

Comment: Do manual do gcc 9.1: "GCC allows the ‘$’ character in identifiers as an extension for most targets. This is true regardless of the std= switch, since this extension cannot conflict with standards-conforming programs. When preprocessing assembler, however, dollars are not identifier characters by default. "

Answer (score 2):

Você não usou `{` corretamente.
While ta fora da função main.
Você colocou `int main();`
Por isso a função dar erro e não executava.

Solução para o problema.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int dinheiro = 200;
int r$100, r$50, r$20, r$10, r$5, r$2, r$1;
int inter;
    while(dinheiro > 0) {
        if (dinheiro >= 100) {
        r$100 = dinheiro/100;
            dinheiro = dinheiro - r$100*100;
        }
        else{r$100 = 0;}
        if((dinheiro >= 50) && (dinheiro < 100)) {
        r$50 = dinheiro/50;
            dinheiro = dinheiro - r$50*50;
        }
        else{r$50 = 0;}
        if ((dinheiro >= 20) && (dinheiro < 50)) {
        r$20 = dinheiro/20;
            dinheiro = dinheiro - r$20*20 ;
        }
        else{r$20 = 0;}
        if ((dinheiro >= 10) && (dinheiro < 20)) {
        r$10 = dinheiro/10;
            dinheiro = dinheiro - r$10*10;
        }
        else{r$10 = 0;}
        if ((dinheiro >= 5) && (dinheiro < 10)) {
        r$5 = dinheiro/5;
            dinheiro = dinheiro - r$5*5;
        }
        else{r$5 = 0;}
        if ((dinheiro >= 2) && (dinheiro < 10)) {
        r$2 = dinheiro/2;
            dinheiro = dinheiro - r$2*2;
        }
        else{r$2 = 0;}
        if ((dinheiro >= 1) && (dinheiro < 1)) {
        r$1 = dinheiro/1;
            dinheiro = dinheiro - r$1*1;
        }
        else{r$1 = 0;}

        printf("notas de r$100 = %d\n", r$100);
        printf("notas de r$50 = %d\n", r$50);
        printf("notas de r$20 = %d\n", r$20);
        printf("notas de r$10 = %d\n", r$10);
        printf("notas de r$5 = %d\n", r$5);
        printf("notas de r$2 = %d\n", r$2);
        printf("notas de r$1 = %d\n", r$1);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maury edite sua resposta, coloque os códigos e mensagens de erros como texto e não como imagem!

Comment: Ok. Mas ficou porque usei navegador do celular. Me desculpe.

Answer (score 1):

Você faz uma série de operações desnecessárias. Basta:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int dinheiro = 200;
    int r$100, r$50, r$20, r$10, r$5, r$2, r$1;
    int inter;
    r$100 = dinheiro / 100;
    dinheiro %= 100;
    r$50 = dinheiro / 50;
    dinheiro %= 50;
    r$20 = dinheiro / 20;
    dinheiro %= 20;
    r$10 = dinheiro / 10;
    dinheiro %= 10;
    r$5 = dinheiro / 5;
    dinheiro %= 5;
    r$2 = dinheiro / 2;
    dinheiro %= 2;
    r$1 = dinheiro;
    printf("notas de r$100 = %d\n", r$100);
    printf("notas de r$50 = %d\n", r$50);
    printf("notas de r$20 = %d\n", r$20);
    printf("notas de r$10 = %d\n", r$10);
    printf("notas de r$5 = %d\n", r$5);
    printf("notas de r$2 = %d\n", r$2);
    printf("notas de r$1 = %d\n", r$1);
    return 0;
}
```

Se você utilizar array pode simplificar ainda mais.

Answer (score 1):

Posso te dar uma LISTA de erros que foram cometidos aí.

Pra começar, não existe uma função `main()`,o que faz o código nem ao menos ser executavel (SE, e apenas se, o compilador aceitá-lo).

Ao invés de fazer todas aquelas condicionais (`if`'s e `else`'s), junto com aquele `while` ali, por que não substituir por código como esse:

```
dinheiro %= x;
r$x = dinheiro / x;
dinheiro %= y;
r$y = dinheiro/y;
```

assim como o usuário "anônimo" fez?

O código é confuso e estranho, além de ter pontos como esse

```
int main();
{int dinheiro = 200};
int r$100, r$50, r$20, r$10, r$5, r$2, r$1;
int inter;
```

onde eu não faço a mínima ideia do que estava tentando ser feito.

Minha dica: dá uma olhada em um cursinho básico de `C`/`C++` no `YouTube`, acessa sites como o `Apostilando`, ou o `Programação Progressiva` que tu vai entender melhor o que tá acontecendo (até porque simplesmente colocar o código aqui não me ajuda em muita coisa se eu não souber sua dúvida).